# How to print a Arraylist of Strings in Jasper 4.5.1 using Struts plugin

Tags: struts2, arraylist, struts, jasper-reports

Has anyone managed to print an ArrayList within a Javabean in Struts using Jasper reports 4.5.0

In my test case I am using a Collection as a field and passing it as a subdataset, using the _THIS I have managed to print the array of strings in my Javabean...

According to [Jasper](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html): A special field mapping can be used to access the current JavaBean object itself. Thus, when a field uses _THIS as description or name, the data source will return the current JavaBean object as field value.

```
<field name="facilities" class="java.util.Collection">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[facilities]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

where the subdatase is:

```
<subDataset name="facilities Dataset">
    <field name="facility" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
```

in order to print the list of string using the listComponent i use

```
<c:list xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="facilities Dataset">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{facilities}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <c:listContents height="10" width="180">
                        <frame>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="10"/>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement style="ListComp" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="10"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="html"/>
                                <textFieldExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["<li>" +$F{facility} +"</li>"]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </frame>
                    </c:listContents>
```

For struts I replaced the Collection class in my field with

```
org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.ValueStackDataSource
```

Although it does print the correct number of strings in the array the value printed is null.

Comment: have you looked at struts2 plugin for Jasper report which provides some wrapper around Jasper to work closely with S2?

Comment: Use JRBeanCollectionDataSource to print ArrayList on JasperReport. Why aren't you using iReport tool and Struts-Jasper-Plugin? Please, as @UmeshAwasthi said, look at struts-jasper-plugin tutorial. It will make your work much easier and you won't need to write XML.

Comment: As i said in my question I am using Struts Jasper Plugin. If you see the sources of the plugin it does not seam to deal with BeanPropertyName. Whereas JRAbstractBeanDataSource 4.5.1 implements return getBeanProperty(bean, getPropertyName(field)); . Iam looking for such a work around. How would a get the valu from the Struts ValueStack???